# FTP transfer shows complete which is not true

Tags: linux, ftp

We have linux machine and we see while doing FTP from the Client to the FTP Server it comes out saying complete as follows but it uploads only some portion of the file.

I don't see any broken error for the file in between of anything about FTP.

Any idea would be great.

```
226 Transfer complete.  MD5=47b37cf8365fa1ac412fb8d14c391647 ("/file_N99274.tar.gz" ) STOR
```

Comment: Was the file still being written when you started the FTP upload? Like when you put the tar command into background and didn't wait for completion?

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner, File was already there.

Comment: Maybe adding more detail would help. What client and server programs and operating systems are being used? What is the original file size, what is the size of the resulting file? Can you determine if only the final part of the file is missing?